# Highcharts Display Issue

Tags: highcharts

The problem that is faced is that the plotLines in bar charts with negative stack disappear based on the data of the series.

For example, if the data that is given is [{"data":[23.0]},{"data":[-0.0]}], the chart looks like:
[image: A version of issue]

PlotLines at [-47,28]

Same related issue when data is [{"data":[10.0]},{"data":[-12.0]}]:
[image: B version of issue]

PlotLines at [-33,14]

Finally, the issue could look like the below image if data is [{"data":[22.7]},{"data":[-24.3]}]:
[image: C Version of issue]

PlotLines at [-36,8]

Example code for the different charts:

```js
$.getJSON('targets.json', function(jsonplotdata) {
      $.getJSON('chart.json', function(datajsp) {
        var chart = new Highcharts.chart({
          chart: {
            renderTo: 'chart',
            plotBackgroundColor: null,
            plotBorderWidth: 0,
            plotShadow: false,
            type: 'bar',
          },
          credits: {
            enabled: false
          },
          lang: {
            noData: "No Data Available!"
          },
          title: {
            text: ''
          },
          xAxis: {
            labels: {
              enabled: false
            },
            lineWidth: 0,
            minorTickLength: 0,
            tickLength: 0,
            gridLineWidth: 0,
            minorGridLineWidth: 0,
            categories: ['']
          },
          yAxis: {
            labels: {
              enabled: false,
            },
            plotLines: [{
              color: 'black',
              dashStyle: 'Solid',
              zIndex: 5,
              width: 1,
              label: {
                text: 'Target<br/>47 kg/t',
                style: {
                  fontSize: "10px",
                  fontFamily: 'sans-serif'
                },
                rotation: 0,
                align: 'center',
                x: 25,
              }
            }, {
              color: 'black',
              dashStyle: 'Solid',
              zIndex: 5,
              width: 1,
              label: {
                text: 'Target<br/>28 kg/t',
                style: {
                  fontSize: "10px",
                  fontFamily: 'sans-serif'
                },
                rotation: 0,
                align: 'center',
                x: -25,
              }
            }],
            gridLineWidth: 0,
            minorGridLineWidth: 0,
            title: {
              text: ''
            }
          },
          colors: ['#4572A7', '#AA4643'],
          legend: {
            enabled: false,
          },
          tooltip: {
            enabled: false,
          },
          plotOptions: {
            series: {

              stacking: 'normal',
              pointWidth: 60
            }
          },
          series: [{
            name: 'chart',
            data: [],
            dataLabels: {
              enabled: true,
              x: 16,
              format: '{series.name}<br/>{point.y} kg/t',
              style: {
                align: 'center',
                fontSize: "10px",
                fontWeight: 'normal',
                textOutline: false,
                fontFamily: 'sans-serif',
                'text-anchor': 'middle'
              }
            }
          }, {
            name: 'Lime + Dolo',
            data: [],
            dataLabels: {
              enabled: true,
              x: 25,
              formatter: function() {
                return this.series.name + '<br/>' + Math.abs(this.y) + ' kg/t';
              },
              style: {
                color: 'white',
                align: 'center',
                fontSize: "10px",
                fontWeight: 'normal',
                textOutline: false,
                fontFamily: 'sans-serif',
                'text-anchor': 'middle'
              }
            }
          }],
        });

        datajsp.forEach(function(datajsp, i) {
          chart.series[i].setData(datajsp.data);

          chart.yAxis[0].options.plotLines[0].value = jsonplotdata[0];
          chart.yAxis[0].options.plotLines[1].value = jsonplotdata[1];
          chart.yAxis[0].update();

        });

      });
```

The expected view is as: [image: Fine View]

I am looking for the best approach to overcome this issue.

Comment: Could you reproduce this issue in online code editor like jsfiddle, codepen with sample data?

Comment: Hi @WojciechChmiel, here it is https://jsfiddle.net/a6cnLwy3/ Just change the first series data to 63 and then both plotLines are shown.

Comment: Thanks for the example. I've changed the values and haven't noticed any issue. Check this: http://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/jg35e21c/

Comment: @WojciechChmiel, sorry I think I didn't express myself well. The original jsfiddle I provided should display my problem when the data is Carbon 35 and Lime+Dolo -23. One plotLine is not shown. When change to Carbon 35 and Lime+Dolo -63 is the expected behavior, both plotlines are shown.

Comment: It is not rendered because it is out of the plot area. With initial values, the min for plotline to be rendered is -30. Check this: http://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/8damp3jL/1/

Comment: @WojciechChmiel, thanks. Is there an easy way to detect once the plotLines are going beyond the plot area and thus render those to the limit of the plotArea as you did manually?

Comment: Just check axis min and max - when a value is lower then axis min it is not rendered. You can add plotline dynamically using `axis.addPlotLine` method. Check this example: http://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/wL950e76/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The last suggestion of @WojciechChmiel worked perfectly! However, it seems like the easiest way was to add scatter series as suggeested in this link: https://www.highcharts.com/forum/viewtopic.php?t=34848

The below series were added:

`{
    name:"Target 47",
    type:'scatter',
    marker:{
        enabled:false
    },
    data:[-75]
},{
    name:"Target 28",
    type:'scatter',
    marker:{
        enabled:false
    },
    data:[28]
}`

The correct position of the target for the negative stack bar, -47, is accomplished by setting it to -75, the sum of 28+47.